# Rasterize monthly mesh data

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, rasterization, mesh

I am working with QGIS and I would like to rasterize mesh data ([ERA5 monthly averaged data on temperature](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels-monthly-means?tab=form)) from 1998 to 2018 in order to perform zonal statistics. However, given the huge number of files that I would generate, I was looking for a more efficient way to rasterize these mesh data than the manual rasterize function provided by QGIS.

Comment: Search for Batch processing

Comment: I thought about that approach, my only concern was about the time-consuming task to fulfill manually the "time" section for each monthly file.

Comment: How are you converting one file, some processing tool?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have GRIB format data-files, you could extract the relevant info using the [ecCodes](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC/ecCodes+Home) tools

Then follow this guide to pull out CSV data

https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/How+to+convert+GRIB+to+CSV

CSV "X,Y,Z" data can then (if needed) be converted to TIFF image data, which might be more useful, depending on what analysis tools you're using

https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html